# Page not linking to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone see any issues with the following code and why my site wouldn't link up with Jquery?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src ="script.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: How do you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If code in `script.js` is dependent on `jquery` then change the order of loading

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src ="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Ah perfect. That does the trick! Thanks!